# Adding font-awesome to UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, font-awesome

I really like to embed font-awesome (http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) in my iOS application to use it in a UIWebView.

I added font-awesome to my project through File -> Add Files to "project"... I checked both options "Copy items into destination group's folder" and "Create folder references for any added folders". This has resulted in a "font-awesome-4.0.3" folder in the root of my project.

Up till now I haven't figured out how to reference the font-awesome css from the HTML in my UIWebView.  As a test, I wrote some code that loads one of the css files and logs its contents:

```
NSString *path = [NSBundle pathForResource:@"font-awesome" ofType:@"css" inDirectory:@"font-awesome-4.0.3/css"];
NSString *css = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];   
NSLog(@"%@", css);
```

Which gives the following output:

```
2014-02-08 17:55:04.364 project[7729:70b] (null)
```

Could it have something to do with the dots in the directory and file names used by font-awesome?

Oh and btw, I know there are projects like https://github.com/alexdrone/ios-fontawesome, but those can't be used in a UIWebView (or can they?)

Edit: I have some more information, stringWithContentsOfFile throws a NSFileReadInvalidFileNameError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this had nothing to do with special chars whatsoever. Stupid mistake:

```
NSString *path = [NSBundle pathForResource:@"font-awesome" ofType:@"css" inDirectory:@"font-awesome-4.0.3/css"];
```

should have been:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"font-awesome" ofType:@"css" inDirectory:@"font-awesome-4.0.3/css"];
```